# Converter returns value, but nothing happens

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, ivalueconverter

I'm trying to bind custom textbox's BorderBrush/Foreground to its Text
The TextToBrush converter is called on Text change and the correct Brush is returned, but the actual foreground remains black and the actual border is not visible at all.
What am I doing wrong?

TextBox Style:

```
  <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="ScaleInputStyle">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Grid >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ScaleBgnd}" />
                        </Grid.Background>

                        <Border x:Name="InputBorder"
                                Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                CornerRadius="5"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">

                            <TextBox x:Name="Input"
                                     Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                                     MaxLength="4"
                                     BorderThickness="0"
                                     BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                                     Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                     FontSize="40"
                                     TextAlignment="Center"
                                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                     VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                     Background="Transparent" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>                        
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

TextBox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="ScaleInput"
                         Text="{Binding ElementName=PhotoDisplay, Path=PhotoImage.ScaleSize, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource TxtBoxToDoubleAndBack}}"
                         Style="{StaticResource ScaleInputStyle}"
                         Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4"
                         Foreground="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource TextToBrush}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
                         Width="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                         BorderBrush="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource TextToBrush}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" 
                         BorderThickness="3" 
                         IsEnabled="{Binding Path=ActionMode, ElementName=PhotoDisplay, Converter={StaticResource ActionToEnable}, ConverterParameter=EnableOnEvaluate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Converter:

```
public class ConvertTextToBrush : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return Brushes.OrangeRed;
        }

        return Regex.IsMatch(value.ToString(), @"^((\d{1,2})(.\d)?)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline)
                   ? Brushes.DodgerBlue
                   : Brushes.OrangeRed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm very sceptical about TextBox inside TextBox template. Most likely it breaks lots of functionality. I suggest to study default TextBox template and tweak it. Also `{TemplateBinding Text}` is bad idea, because TemplateBinding is one way and it won't return changed input to binding source

Comment: it is working fine here. the problem might be related to other parts of the code.